# Dependecies error while eas build with expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, google-signin

While trying to build an .apk file with expo, i got this error:

[stderr] npm

[stderr] ERR! code ERESOLVE

[stderr] npm

[stderr] ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

[stderr] npm ERR!

[stderr] npm

[stderr] ERR! While resolving: @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@8.2.1

[stderr] npm

[stderr] ERR! Found: @expo/config-plugins@5.0.4

[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

[stderr] npm ERR!   @expo/config-plugins@"^5.0.4" from the root project

[stderr] npm ERR!

[stderr] @expo/config-plugins@"~5.0.3" from @expo/cli@0.4.9

[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@expo/cli

[stderr] npm ERR!     @expo/cli@"0.4.9" from expo@47.0.5

[stderr] npm ERR!     node_modules/expo

[stderr] npm ERR!       expo@"~47.0.5" from the root project

[stderr] npm ERR!       12 more (expo-application, expo-constants, expo-dev-client, ...)

[stderr] npm ERR!   5 more (@expo/config, @expo/prebuild-config, ...)

[stderr] npm ERR!

[stderr] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

[stderr] npm ERR! peerOptional @expo/config-plugins@"^4.1.0" from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@8.2.1

[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin

[stderr] npm ERR!   @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@"^8.2.1" from the root project

[stderr] npm ERR!

[stderr] npm

[stderr] ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @expo/config-plugins@4.1.5

[stderr] npm ERR! node_modules/@expo/config-plugins

[stderr] npm ERR!   peerOptional @expo/config-plugins@"^4.1.0" from @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@8.2.1

[stderr] npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin

[stderr] npm ERR!     @react-native-google-signin/google-signin@"^8.2.1" from the root project

[stderr] npm ERR!

[stderr] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

[stderr] npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

[stderr] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Can anyone explain to me how can i fix ? i already try --force, npm install, --legacy--peer-deps but nothing ...

thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5):

this occurs because `@react-native-google-signin/google-signin` has a peer dependency on an old version of `@expo/config-plugins`. if you aren't seeing this locally, then you may be using an older version of npm - this error message will occur in npm 7 and higher due to how peer dependency handling changed in that version. [see this issue](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues/1104).

you can do any of the following to work around it:

- set the npm version on EAS Build to match your local version. you can do this by installing that specific npm version in an [EAS Build pre-install hook](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/npm-hooks/)
- set the legacy peer deps option in an [EAS Build pre-install hook](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/npm-hooks/): `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`
- create a `.npmrc` in your project, set `legacy-peer-deps` to true in it, add that to git
- switch to yarn classic: install yarn classic, delete `package-lock.json`, run `yarn` in your project to generate `yarn.lock`, run build.